# Assign mutiple ranges (non consecutive) to a single Constants (apps script)

Tags: javascript, variables, google-apps-script, constants

I have this (below) as part of my apps script and I am wondering if there is a way to simplify this:

`const fieldRange = ["C9","C10","C11","C12","C15","C16","C17","C18","C19","C20","C21","C22","C23","C24","C25","C26","C27","C28","C29","C30","C33","C34","C35","C36","C37","C38","C41","C42","C45","C46","C47","C48","C49","C50"]`

maybe something like `['(C9:C12)','(C15:C30)'`, etc.

Comment: Did my answer show you the result that you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue as you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. If you have issues with my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike. My original issue is that my googlesheet file is running slow and I suspected that it is due to my codes not written properly (although it is working). So I thought I can simplify a part of the code. However, I am very new to this and the sample script you provided are even longer (not what I was expecting so I haven't used it - I want to understand the code first before trying it).

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand whether your issue was resolved. Can I ask you about it? If my answer was not useful, I have to apologize.

Comment: By the way, about `My original issue is that my googlesheet file is running slow and I suspected that it is due to my codes not written properly (although it is working).`, in this case, is your this question different from your actual question? If my understanding is correct, I apologize for my answer.

Comment: I just want to simplify this script "   const fieldRange = ["C9","C10","C11","C12","C15","C16","C17","C18","C19","C20","C21","C22","C23","C24","C25","C26","C27","C28","C29","C30","C33","C34","C35","C36","C37","C38","C41","C42","C45","C46","C47","C48","C49","C50"]   " and your suggestion doesn't simplify it (because I don't understand it, it's my limitation) but thanks for checking on it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In my sample script, your value is converted to `["C9:C12","C15:C30","C33:C38","C41:C42","C45:C50"]`. So, from `your suggestion doesn't simplify it`, I cannot understand your expected value. I apologize for this. That output value is not your expected value? I would like to support you. So, can I ask you about the detail of your expected value?

Comment: I have 2 questions. 1. You want to retrieve the value of `["C9:C12","C15:C30","C33:C38","C41:C42","C45:C50"]` from `const fieldRange = ["C9","C10","C11","C12","C15","C16","C17","C18","C19","C20","C21","C22","C23","C24","C25","C26","C27","C28","C29","C30","C33","C34","C35","C36","C37","C38","C41","C42","C45","C46","C47","C48","C49","C50"]`. Is my understanding correct? 2. Your quesiton is your expected question. Is my understanding correct? I'm worried whether I misunderstood your expected `simplify` of `your suggestion doesn't simplify it`. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
// This value is from your question.
const fieldRange = ["C9", "C10", "C11", "C12", "C15", "C16", "C17", "C18", "C19", "C20", "C21", "C22", "C23", "C24", "C25", "C26", "C27", "C28", "C29", "C30", "C33", "C34", "C35", "C36", "C37", "C38", "C41", "C42", "C45", "C46", "C47", "C48", "C49", "C50"];

// Ref: https://tanaikech.github.io/2021/10/08/compiling-continuous-numbers-using-google-apps-script/
const compilingNumbers = (ar) => {
  const { values } = [...new Set(ar.sort((a, b) => a - b))].reduce((o, e, i, a) => {
    if (o.temp.length == 0 || (o.temp.length > 0 && e == o.temp[o.temp.length - 1] + 1)) {
      o.temp.push(e);
    } else {
      if (o.temp.length > 0) {
        o.values.push({ start: o.temp[0], end: o.temp[o.temp.length - 1] });
      }
      o.temp = [e];
    }
    if (i == a.length - 1) {
      o.values.push(o.temp.length > 1 ? { start: o.temp[0], end: o.temp[o.temp.length - 1] } : { start: e, end: e });
    }
    return o;
  }, { temp: [], values: [] });
  return values;
};

const r1 = fieldRange.reduce((o, e) => {
  const k = e.replace(/[0-9]+/, "");
  const v = Number(e.toUpperCase().replace(/[A-Z]+/, ""));
  o[k] = o[k] ? [...o[k], v] : [v];
  return o;
}, {});
const res = Object.entries(r1).flatMap(([k, v]) => compilingNumbers(v).map(({ start, end }) => `${k}${start}:${k}${end}`));
console.log(res); // ["C9:C12","C15:C30","C33:C38","C41:C42","C45:C50"]
```

- When this script is run, `["C9:C12","C15:C30","C33:C38","C41:C42","C45:C50"]` is obtained.
- If you want to retrieve the value like `maybe something like ['(C9:C12)','(C15:C30)', etc.`, please modify `${k}${start}:${k}${end}` to `(${k}${start}:${k}${end})`.

#### Note:

- From your showing sample value, this script supposes that all values in your expected array including A1Notation are only one cell. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)